# R barplot: NAs not allowed in xlim

Tags: r

I tried to plot x versus y as shown below

```
   test1 <- data.frame(x = c(26, 21, 20), y = c("a", "b", "c"))
   plot(test1$y,test1$x)
```

But I get below error. How to I handle this?

```
 Error in plot.window(xlim, ylim, log = log, ...) : 
 NAs not allowed in 'xlim'
 In addition: Warning messages:
 1: In mean.default(width) :
 argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
 2: In Ops.factor(width, 2) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
 3: In Ops.factor(space, width) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
 4: In Ops.factor(width, 2) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
 5: In Ops.factor(space, width) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: What kind of plot do you want to create?

Comment: Simple barplot. I also tried with barplot function but same error

Comment: Switch x and y.

Comment: i also tried that, But no output

Comment: `with(test1, barplot(setNames(x, y)))`.

Comment: `library(ggplot2); ggplot(test1, aes(y, x)) + geom_col()`

Comment: `barplot(x ~ y, test1)` works - I just tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I run your code and it went normal, 
and the plot is like that.[image: Output Plot]